# Pandas - Create dataframe column & populate with values from an exiting column based on date and category

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that shows sales per item per store, it looks like this:

```
date         item   storeNbr   Sales
2021-06-29   soap   123        100
2021-05-29   hat    129        500
2020-06-29   soap   123        0
2020-05-29   hat    129        10
```

I'm trying to create a column for last year's sales that should take values that
already exist in the dataframe where the date is equal to the prior year, and where
the store number and item are the same. So it should look like this:

```
date         item   storeNbr   Sales   LY
2021-06-29   soap   123        100     0
2021-05-29   hat    129        500     10
2020-06-29   soap   123        0       Nan
2020-05-29   hat    129        10      Nan
```

I've tried this:

```
df['Previous'] = 
df.groupby([df['date'].dt.month,df['date'].dt.day,df['StoreNbr']]) 
['Sales'].shift()
```

but I'm having trouble getting the desired result. Thank you in advance for any help here!

Comment: You could just do `.shift(-1)` to get the _previous_ value instead of the next. (assuming your years are sorted in descending order as in the example)

Answer (score 1):

**Sample data:**

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': {0: Timestamp('2021-06-29 00:00:00'), 1: Timestamp('2021-05-29 00:00:00'), 2: Timestamp('2020-06-29 00:00:00'), 3: Timestamp('2020-05-29 00:00:00')}, 'item': {0: 'soap', 1: 'hat', 2: 'soap', 3: 'hat'}, 'storeNbr': {0: 123, 1: 129, 2: 123, 3: 129}, 'Sales': {0: 100, 1: 500, 2: 0, 3: 10}})
```

**Code:**

```
# create copy of your data, but add 1 year from the date, then merge.
df2 = df.copy()
df2['date'] = df2['date'] + pd.DateOffset(years=1)
df['LY'] = df.drop('Sales', axis=1).merge(df2, on=['date', 'item', 'storeNbr'])['Sales']
```

**Output:**

```
        date  item  storeNbr  Sales    LY
0 2021-06-29  soap       123    100   0.0
1 2021-05-29   hat       129    500  10.0
2 2020-06-29  soap       123      0   NaN
3 2020-05-29   hat       129     10   NaN
```

One-liner provide by @ScottBoston

```
df.merge(df.assign(date = df['date'] + pd.DateOffset(years=1)), 
         on=['date','item','storeNbr'], 
         how='left', 
         suffixes=('','_y'))\
  .rename(columns={'Sales_y':'LY'})
```

Comment: Mind if update your answer?  Please delete edits if you would like.

Comment: @ScottBoston, nice edit and use of assign! One question though, would't it be shorter and easier to read if you replaced the suffix/rename part with a .drop() on the first df instead? `df.drop('Sales', axis=1).merge(...)`

Comment: Yes.   You can do that way also.

Answer (score 0):

If you sort it first, you can do a groupby and shift.

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['item','date'])
df['LY'] = df.groupby('item')['Sales'].shift()
```

Output

```
        date  item  storeNbr  Sales    LY
3 2020-05-29   hat       129     10   NaN
1 2021-05-29   hat       129    500  10.0
2 2020-06-29  soap       123      0   NaN
0 2021-06-29  soap       123    100   0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is close, just 3 minor changes:

1. group by one more field on `item`
2. add the parameter `sort=False` in `groupby()` to ensure the original order is retained (recent year first).
3. use `shift(-1)` to get the value of 'next' value instead of `shift()` which gets previous value.

---

```
df['LY'] = df.groupby([df['date'].dt.month ,df['date'].dt.day , df['storeNbr'], df['item']], sort=False)['Sales'].shift(-1)
```

Result:

```
print(df)

        date  item  storeNbr  Sales    LY
0 2021-06-29  soap       123    100   0.0
1 2021-05-29   hat       129    500  10.0
2 2020-06-29  soap       123      0   NaN
3 2020-05-29   hat       129     10   NaN
```